# How to access httpapplicationcontext variable from aspx page?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, c#-4.0

I have created a Application variable to in my Global.asax.cs file with the below code:-

```
protected void Application_Start(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{    
    Application["Visitors"] = 0;
}

protected void Session_Start(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     Application.Lock(); 
     Application["Visitors"] = Convert.ToInt32(Application["Visitors"]) + 1;
     Application.UnLock();
}

protected void Session_End(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     Application["Visitors"] = Convert.ToInt32(Application["Visitors"]) - 1;
}
```

Now I want to use this `Application["Visitor"]` variable in my **Classic aspx page**. I am writing below code for this but it is giving me error:-

```
Sub window_onLoad ()

     dim i 
     i= Application["Visitors"].ToString()

End sub
```

Could you please help me in using this variable on different aspx pages?

Comment: what error you are getting , please share.

Comment: Microsoft VBScript runtime error: Type mismatch: 'Application'

Answer (score 2):

If you are using vb.net, use have to use () brackets instead of []:

```
Sub window_onLoad ()
 dim i 
 i= Application("Visitors").ToString()
End sub
```

Comment: I am getting below error after implementing the changes you suggested:-Microsoft VBScript runtime error: Type mismatch: 'Application'

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to get the server side `Application` values on client side VB script? Is it so? than I think it is not possible, you will have to do it in server side code.

Comment: Yes I am trying to get the Server side Application values on client ide VB script. So you mean that in every case I have to create a seperate variable?

Comment: In server side code, get the values from Application variables and assign them to some hidden fields and than in VB Script use the values from hidden fields.